# Sql Developer Setup

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone help in resolving this error? Please check attached screenshot. How can I get those salgrade, employee, courses those tables? I did a lot of online search but couldn't resolve.

[image]

```
C:\>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 19-JUL-2018 22:42:15

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                19-JUL-2018 20:58:06
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 44 min. 9 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   
    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         
    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\log\listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC_FOR_XEipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-7MR8EOF)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE_XPT" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Do you have a local database to connect to as the dialog shows localhost ?

Comment: You can try the "System" login and see if it changes your error message

Comment: Where did you get the connection information from? You might just need to change the radio button at the bottom from 'SID' to 'Service name' and put the `XE` value in that box instead. Or your service name could be `orcl`, or something else... Running `lsnrctl services` will show you the correct value to use.

Comment: I tried using the username as **hr** and password as **hr** and SID as XE and again changed the Service name to XE but still I am getting this error _Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor_ . @GrantWinney

Comment: By local database you mean what can you please specify? Like I saw online videos where they installed SQL Developer and put in the credentials and it started working but for me it is giving errors... @KrisRice

Comment: I tried changing the radio button to **Service Name** and set to the value to **XE** once and **ORCL** once but same error **Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor**. Like if you can help setup this SQL Developer, please help. I want to get the default Oracle tables like employee, salgrade and I want to run queries on them and learn Sql. @AlexPoole

Comment: Like I said before, run `lsnrctl services` to see what service names are valid. If it doesn't list any (except internal ones) then you might have another issue. Check that first, but also check the DB is actually up and running. If the DB is up then but *not* shown in `lsnrctl services` then it might not be able to register with the listener. One step at a time though...

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me how do I run **lsnrctl services**. Is it going to cmd and type _lsnrctl start_. If it is that it is showing this in cmd _TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started_. I am not seeing any service names as such @AlexPoole

Comment: Just type `lsnrctl services` instead of `lsnrctl start`. Or at this point it might be more useful to do `lsnrctl status` and paste that into the question, as it will show those and other information. (As formatted text, not an image!)

Comment: I have added the output of `lsnrctl status`. Can you please check and see if any help possible. Thanks @AlexPoole

Comment: OK, so that's saying service `xe` is available, so you should be able to connect by giving that as the service name (not SID) in the SQL Developer connection dialog. It looks like `DESKTOP-7MR8EOF` must resolve to the same IP as localhost, 127.0.0.1. (Or, you have two listeners running, but I don't think XE allows that.)

Comment: Connection Name: Anything
Username: ?
Password: ?
Connection Type: Basic
Role: default
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
Service name: xe  I am providing the following.. Username and password can be **hr** and **hr** or anything else? If providing hr & hr, getting this error `Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor `

Comment: What happens if you change the hostname from `localhost` to `DESKTOP-7MR8EOF`?

Comment: If I change the hostname from localhost to DESKTOP-7MR8EOF and use the username and password I set when I installed Oracle XE 10g it works. But how do I get those tables like employees, salgrade, etc. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have two listeners running on your PC. That is confusing and a bit unusual, so you might want to check your configuration files, run `netca` to see what that thinks is happening. You might have two Oracle installations (not sure if that's possible with XE) or a misconfigured service or startup script. Or you might actually need both for some reason. (Be careful changing things though...)

One is listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1521 but doesn't have an XE or ORCL database/service registered against it. It may or may not have another DB/service registered. You were trying to connect to your database via that listener, but as it wasn't registered, it correctly gave you the "listener does not currently know of service requested" error message.

The other is listening on your PC's network address, which is whatever your host name `DESKTOP-7MR8EOF`, also on port 1521. Your XE database has registered against that listener, which is the default behaviour - to use the server name to find the listener to register with.

If you run `netstat -an | find "1521"` from a command prompt you will see two entries listening on port 1521, one for 127.0.0.1 and one for whatever IP `DESKTOP-7MR8EOF` currently resolves to (which might change on reboot if you're using DHCP).

As already discovered in comments, you just need to change your connection setting in SQL Developer to also use your PC name instead of 127.0.0.1. You will then hit the correct listener.

---

If you are connecting as `HR` you should already have sample tables available. If that user doesn't exist and you're connecting as a different user ("the username and password I set when I installed Oracle XE 10g" suggests you might be connecting as `SYS`, which isn't something you should do regularly) then [there are instructions in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14198/installation.htm) for adding the sample schemas. You may also have the `SCOTT` schema available already.